# How do I automate the execution of a perl script in Windows 7/2008?

Tags: windows, perl, automation, task, scheduler

I want to execute a perl script every week or so. I've looked at the Task Scheduler but all it does when I select the .pl file and run the task is open the .pl file in notepad++. I then tried having Task Scheduler run a .bat file:

```
perl goto.pl
```

It works when I double click it on the desktop (which is where I'm working off of) but only flashes a command prompt screen when I run the task. I googled extensively and many people had this problem and the solution seemed to be "change the permissions" or "add the full pathname to perl.exe and the .pl file without quotes around them". The files and the desktop folder all have full control/permissions and I am an admin account so that doesn't seem to be the solution. My perl script outputs to a text file which I would like to have automatically emailed to a distribution list every week but that's a challenge for later. Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you "add the full pathname to perl.exe and the .pl file without quotes around them"?

Comment: I looked briefly at MSDN and it said "executables" quite specifically. therefore, my advice would be to use something like perl2exe , create an executable out of it, go to "Add Scheduled Task" under `Scheduled Tasks`, browse to the exe.. add it.. and you done.

Comment: It just flashes a command prompt screen. So it looks like: c:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe c:\Users\username\Desktop\goto.pl in the batch file.

Comment: I tried perl2exe. I downloaded the "lite" (free) version and it didn't work.

Comment: Is it flashing a command prompt screen because it's finishing the script rather quickly..? Unless you have something coming in from the stdin, that's usually what happens when you double click scripts.

Comment: Oh ok. Well I'm just an amatuer, so I'll leave this to the gurus.

Comment: no, that's a good suggestion. It's just that I already tried it and it didn't work lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the current working directory in a .bat file, which seems to be the problem.

```
cd c:\directory\of\script\
perl goto.pl
```

Or you can use full path names, as you suggested yourself in the question.

Comment: Bingo! That was it! Problem solved. Thank you! And everyone else, too!